# Testing rc.d levels

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, linux, update

I have a hierarchy of programs running which have a very specific start and stop order. I think I got the run levels set appropriately, but I'm having issues with some of them not working in the order intended. Is there a way to step through the start-up and shutdown so I can see what's going on as it happens?

Comment: You can change run levels with `telinit` (8) command. If run from the console than you can see the services starting or stopping.

Comment: Any way to actually step through the run level change?

Comment: None that I know off. Just changing whole levels, or manually starting/stopping services.

Comment: I wonder if I could emulate it with for file in /etc/rc(number).d/*; do sudo $file stop; done? Is that basically how it runs, with the assumption that the sort order is the same?

Comment: I am not sure how Ubuntu orders it. Alphabetical order is unlikely though. There will be some kind of intelligent order (like bring up network before bring up NFS). -- The people on our sister site http://askubuntu.com/ might have more helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

The way debian/ubuntu orders the `rc(number).d` bootup is:

**0 to 6** for the runlevel, 0 for halt, 6 for reboot, etc.

**K** at the beginning of the link for Kill.

**S** at the beginning of the link for Start.

The number after the K/S is the order in which they start inside each run level from low to high.

examples:

```
/etc/rc3.d/S20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
```

starts before:

```
/etc/rc3.d/S75sudo -> ../init.d/sudo
```

The comand to update the runlevels is `update-rc.d`.

example from [debuntu](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/):

- starting apache with priority 20 on runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5 and Kill with priority 80 on runlevels 0, 1 and 6

  ```
  update-rc.d apache2 start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 80 0 1 6
  ```

Comment: That's true.  However, the deeper answer is that update-rc.d automatically figures out the priorities by looking at the dependencies declared in each init script's header comments.  See the `update-rc.d(8)` and `insserv(8)` man pages.  You should avoid manually managing the start/stop priorities and declare your dependencies instead.